# Is flowUid a standard part of a SOAP response from Amadeus

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, amadeus

I am a PHP developpeur, and need to fix a bug in a SOAP request.
But my comprehension of SOAP is limited.

In this SOAP response from the webservice Amadeus :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
    <flowUId xmlns="http://ws.amadeus.fr/addressing">8d04300a-68db-4d1b-8cfd-22bf35113df2</flowUId>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    [...]
</soap:Body>
```

What is `<flowUid>` ?
Is `<flowUid>` a part of SOAP itself ?
Is it generated by my SOAP client (the PHP object \SoapClient) ?
Or is it a part of the logic from the webservice ?

I don't know witch documentation i need read to understand better this response.

Answer (score 0):

Reponse from Amadeus : the `<flowUid>` is a part of the webservice business logic.
It is not from any SOAP specification.